# Passing parameters from Activity to doInBackground method, Async Task

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to pass a variable "chartUrl" from JsonActivity to the doInBackground method as shown below. I've tried to change the arguments but that did not work. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Code :

public class JsonActivity extends ListActivity{

```
 private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    // JSON Node names

    private static final String TAG_RANK = "rank";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
   String chartUrl;

    String[] urlNames = new String[] { 
            "myurls"

            };

 // chartItemList holds the chart items 
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> chartItemList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, 
        String>>();
    JsonParser Parser = new JsonParser();

    JSONArray chartItems = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.listlayout);

      //Get the bundle from other activity
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        //Extract chart index from the bundle
        int chartIndex = bundle.getInt("chartIndex");
        String chartUrl = urlNames[chartIndex]; 


        //Check if the user has a connection

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            if (!info.isConnected()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please check your connection and try again.", 
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            //if positive, fetch the articles in background
            else new getChartItems().execute(chartUrl);
        }

        //else show toast
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please check your connection and try again.", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }


    class getChartItems extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        // Shows a progress dialog while setting up the background task
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(JsonActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading chart...");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        //Gets the json data for chart items data and presents it in a list view
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


            String json = Parser.getJSONFromUrl(chartUrl);

            String rank;

            String name;

            try{

            chartItems = new JSONArray(json);

            JSONObject json_data=null;

             for(int i=0;i<chartItems.length();i++){

                json_data = chartItems.getJSONObject(i);
                rank=json_data.getString("rank");
                name=json_data.getString("name");


                 HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                 // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                 hashMap.put(TAG_RANK, rank);
                 hashMap.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                 // adding HashMap to ArrayList
                    chartItemList.add(hashMap);

             }


              ;
            }

            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                     System.out.println(chartItemList);

                  //updates the list view with the parsed items
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(JsonActivity.this, chartItemList,
                            R.layout.list_item,
                            new String[] {TAG_RANK,TAG_NAME, }, new int[] 

                         {R.id.rank ,R.id.name});
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
            return null;
        }

        //Removes the progress dialog when the data has been fetched
        protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }


  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
String json = Parser.getJSONFromUrl(args[0]);
```

instead of

```
String json = Parser.getJSONFromUrl(chartUrl);
```

for getting `chartUrl` value in doInBackground method  and if `getChartItems` is inner class of Activity then just declare `chartUrl` as class level variable to access it in whole class